# Multiplication of rational with irrational number?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational number and we know that $ab$ is rational, then what can we say about $a/b$? Is true that it's equal to 0?

Comment: $a = \frac{1}{2}$ and $b = \sqrt{3}$, what are $ab$ and $\frac{a}{b}$ ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. If $ab$ and $a$ are both rational and $a \neq 0$, then $\frac{ab}{a} = b$ is rational as well. Given that $b$ is irrational, we must have $a=0$. Since $b$ is irrational it is nonzero, so $\frac{a}{b}$ is well-defined and equals $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Remark that $a/b=0$ is the same as $a=0$. It is true that the only case where $ab$ is rational is if $a=0$, because otherwise we would have $ab/a$ rational (rational numbers are closed under division), so $b$ rational.